# How do i make this calculator include being able to count decimals aswell?

Tags: android, decimal

I'm new to Android Studio and working on this calculator. The picture below shows the possible adding of two numbers:

:[image]

When i click the "First Number" line all the numbers i can choose pop up. I'm able to count two integers such as 4 + 6 but can't count decimals, for example 3.5 + 2.6. Nothing happens when i click the decimal(.) I can't use (,) or (-) either.

Here's the code on this page of the app:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AdditionPage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button btnAdd;
private TextView AnswTxt;
private EditText FirstNumber, SecondNumber;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_additionssida);
        init();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
    private void init() {
        btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        FirstNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SubTal1);
        SecondNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SecondNumber);
        AnswTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.AnswTxt);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String num1 = FirstNumber.getText().toString();
        String num2 = SecondNumber.getText().toString();
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnAdd:
                float addition = Float.parseFloat(num1) + Float.parseFloat(num2);
                AnswTxt.setText(String.valueOf(addition));
                break;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If nothing happens when you click the decimal, you may have to look at the xml for the layout with the EditText to see what the `android:inputType` is

Comment: double number = Double.parseDouble(FirstNumber.getText().trim());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly possible that you have set the `inputType` attribute of the `EditText`s to be `number`. This will only allow numeric characters to be inputted into the Edit Text.

That's why nothing happens when you press the dot button on the keyboard.

You can try setting it to `numberDecimal`. According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType):

> Can be combined with number and its other options to allow a decimal (fractional) number.

Comment: Yes this did the trick, thank you! :) Before i accept your answer and close this question, what if i also wanted to add negative numbers, for example (-4) + (-2)?

Comment: @Rengaw can you not do negative numbers with `numberDecimal`? That's quite surprising. If that's the case then you will have to set the input type back to `text` and check whether it is a valid number through code. There are a lot of posts here about how to check whether a string is a valid number.

Comment: @Rengaw also, you don't "close" a question after it has been answered. A question is closed if it is off-topic or a duplicate

Comment: No it doesn't work with numberDecimal. And thank you for the tips concerning negative numbers, i'll look more into it.